# Cropping the liquid region of a bottle for processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv

[image]

Basically what I want to do is to filter out only the liquid region of the bottle for further processing. So the next processes would apply only for that region.

I've tried various methods for months but didn't have any luck. I can filter out the region between the top liquid boundary and the top of the bottom dark region. But that doesn't serve my purpose as I need the areas at the sides of the dark region at the bottom of the bottles too. Im trying to do this in openCV/EmguCV.

help please...

Comment: *"I've tried various methods"* - perhaps you could list these in your question and give some idea of why they didn't work. This will avoid people suggesting things you've already tried. Also, perhaps give us an image that you would *like* to get after processing.

Comment: So always you will have the bottle with the same color?

Comment: have you tried watershed? i think you should put more images, 3 or 4 more with different variations. otherwise whatever gets suggested is not very likely to work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may upload the images you have already obtained (code as well), along with the regions that your result failed to include. Currently I am not quite sure which part of liquid would you like to get. I tried some easy processing, and get a liquid region. Please let me know if there is some problem.

(1) Remove the region with (i) intensity of 255 at either R,G or B space, or (ii) all the 3 space with intensity of less than 100, shown in upper left as `I0`;

(2) HSV space. Remove the region with Hue value equal to 0.5 or 1, shown in upper middle as `I1`;

(3) Remove the region with Saturation value no less than 0.5, shown in upper right as `I2`;

(4) `I2&I1`, remove the region with small areas, fill in the holes, shown in lower left as `I3`;

(5) `I0(:,:,1)&I3` where `I0(:,:,1)` is its channel 1. Fill in the holes, smooth the edges, shown in lower middle;

(6) Use (5)'s result as a mask on the original image, shown in the lower right.

[image]

I think you can also get the liquid region with the dark side at the bottom shown as a hole, you can use [cvFloodFill()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_processing.html?highlight=cvfloodfill#cvFloodFill) to fill the holes, and get a intact liquid region.

Comment: I modified your method a bit and it gives a good result. Thumbs up!! Thanks a lot